# Do trained weights depend on the order in which trained data has been input?

Tags: machine-learning, keras

Suppose one makes a neural network using Keras. Do the trained weights depend on the order in which the training data has been fed into the system ? Is it ok to feed data belonging to one category first and then data belonging to another category or should they be random?

Comment: Have you read the answers?

Answer (score 1):

As the training will be done in batches, which means optimizing the weights on data chunk by chunk, the main assumption is that the batches of data are somewhat representative of the dataset. To make it representative it is thus better to randomly sample the data.

Bottomline : It will theoritically learn better if you feed randomly the neural network. I strongly advise yo to shuffle your dataset when you feed it in training mode (and there is an option in the .fit() function).

In inference mode, if you only want to make a forward pass on the neural net, then the order doesn't matter at all since you don't change the weights.

I hope this clarifies things a bit for you :-)

Comment: You are talking about mini- or full-batch training. What if OP is going to perform *online* training when the weights are updated "on-the-fly"?

Comment: online you mean one sample by one sample? Then I guess it doesn't matter. Except if you group the samples in the background and train them by batch. I wasn't talking about mini or full batch training, just saying that you don't usually train on the full dataset at once :)

Comment: Yeah, I know, just there are several types of training, and OP did not mention that in the question, hence my comment.

Comment: The question seemed to come from someone beginning with neural nets, so I assumed that he was speaking about the most usual case where you feed the data batch by batch. Tried to make my answer general in order to give him the tools to understand what's happening when you train the weights of a NN... :) wait and see if it does or doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Nassim answer is believed to be True for small networks and datasets but recent [articles](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.10239.pdf) (or e.g. [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.0233) one) makes us believe that for deeper networks (with more than 4 layers) - not shuffling your data set might be considered as some kind of regularization - as poor minima are expected to be deep but small and good minima are expected to be wide and hard to leave.

In case of inference time - the only way where this might harm your inference process is when you are using a training distribution of your data in a highly coupled manner - e.g. using `BatchNormalization` or `Dropout` like in a training phase (this is sometimes used for some kinds of Bayesian Deep Learning).